# eventListener не улавливает созданные элементы

Tags: javascript, jquery

у мне нужно сделать todo list, то есть когда я нажимаю на checkbox елемент должен пропасть, и все прекрасно работает, только, если создать через кнопку такой же елемент, почему-то обработчик не слушает

```js
$('.main__add-btn').on('click', function() {
  // показать форму 
  $('.main__form-create').show();
})


$('.main__add-task').on('click', function() {

  let valueOfTextarea = $('.main__task-input').val();

  // $('.main__add').append(`<p>${valueOfTextarea}</p>`)

  $('.main__new-tasks').append(`<li class="main__task-in-progress">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="main__task-checkbox" name="taskName" >
            ${valueOfTextarea}
            <label>
        </li>`)
})

let checkbox = $('input[type="checkbox"]')


//
$(document).on('click', '.main__task-checkbox', function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('class'));
    $(this).closest('.main__task-in-progress').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="main">
  <div class="main__add">
    <ul class="main__new-tasks">
      <li class="main__task-in-progress">
        <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="main__task-checkbox" name="taskName" id="task1">
                        выывывы
                    <label>
                </li>
                <li class="main__task-in-progress">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="main__task-checkbox" name="taskName" id="task1">
                        выывывы
                    <label>
                </li>
                <li class="main__task-in-progress">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="main__task-checkbox" name="taskName" id="task1">
                        выывывы
                    <label>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="main__add-btn">Add task</a>
            <div class="main__form-create disabled">
                <form action="#" method="dialog" class="main__form">
                    <div class="main__task-info">
                        <input type="text" class="main__task-input" placeholder="I need to do...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="main__buttons">
                        <button class="main__add-task">Add task</button>
                        <button class="main__cansel">Cansel</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

в данном коде jquery, простите я не знаю как его подключить к Stack

Comment: потому что addEventListener, который вы запускаете вначале не видит вновь созданыне элементы. А почему вы чекбоксом удаляете? )

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне заставить его видеть

Comment: Если используете jquery, то можете при создании новой записи добавить в инпут чекбокса onсlick="$(this).closest('.main__task-in-progress').detach()"

Comment: @BearVorkuta , извините я пока не много опыта имею, не могли бы Вы показать где именно его нужно вставить

Comment: @BearVorkuta я даже пробовал создать <input type="checkbox" class="main__task-checkbox" name="taskName onсlick="console.log('aa')">, и все равно не выполняет код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В момент выполнения кода с созданием блока `.main__task-checkbox`, он не получает от цикла `.addEventListener`, следовательно JS и знать не знает о *новых блоках*.

Лучше всего для такого использовать [делегирование событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation)

на JS

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('main__task-checkbox')) {
    console.log(ee.target.className);
    elem.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
  }
});
```

На JQ

```
$(document).on('click', '.main__task-checkbox', function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('class'));
    $(this).closest('.main__task-in-progress').remove();
});
```

Comment: у меня при выполнении jquery просто undefined в консоль выводит, и не удаляет

Comment: Ваш код отлично работает, только вместо e нужно писать function(), иначе выводит undefined

Comment: @Mageeka, да, верно, забыл исправить. Убрал вообще стрелочные функции, на всякий пожарный)

Comment: а не подскажете почему так произошло, у меня такое впервые вообще

Comment: Что именно? Ваш изначальный вопрос или тут ошибка в ответе?)

Comment: Я имею ввиду, почему при стрелочной функции выводит undefined, а при обычной все нормально?

Comment: @Mageeka, вот эта [статья](https://medium.com/@KucherDev/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-es6-3135a973490b) объяснит почему)